# Magento 2: Rest API add "stock_item" in to the list of the products

Tags: rest-api, stock, magento2.3.0, stock-status, product-listing

Magento 2 product rest API provided `stock_item` details in `/V1/products/:sku` API. But `V1/products` rest API not included `stock_item` details in products.

I want to need `stock_item` details in to the list of the products rest API.

> Method: GET
>
> URL: http://localhost/magentosample230/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=4&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq

**Actual Response:**

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "name": "Joust Duffle Bag",
            "attribute_set_id": 15,
            "price": 34,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "created_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:51",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:51",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "website_ids": [
                    1
                ],
                "category_links": [
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "3"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "product_links": [
                {
                    "sku": "24-MB01",
                    "link_type": "crosssell",
                    "linked_product_sku": "24-WG086",
                    "linked_product_type": "simple",
                    "position": 1
                }
            ],
            "options": [],
            "media_gallery_entries": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "media_type": "image",
                    "label": "Image",
                    "position": 1,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "types": [
                        "image",
                        "small_image",
                        "thumbnail"
                    ],
                    "file": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "tier_prices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "image",
                    "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "small_image",
                    "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "description",
                    "value": "<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.<p>\n<ul>\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\n</ul>"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "sku": "24-MB04",
            "name": "Strive Shoulder Pack",
            "attribute_set_id": 15,
            "price": 32,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "created_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:52",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:52",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "website_ids": [
                    1
                ],
                "category_links": [
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "7"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "product_links": [
                {
                    "sku": "24-MB04",
                    "link_type": "crosssell",
                    "linked_product_sku": "24-UG03",
                    "linked_product_type": "simple",
                    "position": 1
                }
            ],
            "options": [],
            "media_gallery_entries": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "media_type": "image",
                    "label": "Image",
                    "position": 1,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "types": [
                        "image",
                        "small_image",
                        "thumbnail"
                    ],
                    "file": "/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "tier_prices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "image",
                    "value": "/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "small_image",
                    "value": "/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "description",
                    "value": "<p>Convenience is next to nothing when your day is crammed with action. So whether you're heading to class, gym, or the unbeaten path, make sure you've got your Strive Shoulder Pack stuffed with all your essentials, and extras as well.</p>\n<ul>\n<li>Zippered main compartment.</li>\n<li>Front zippered pocket.</li>\n<li>Side mesh pocket.</li>\n<li>Cell phone pocket on strap.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap and top carry handle.</li>\n</ul>"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "activity",
                    "value": "11,21,23,18"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "erin_recommends",
                    "value": "1"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "sale",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
}
```

**Expected Response:**

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "name": "Joust Duffle Bag",
            "attribute_set_id": 15,
            "price": 34,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "created_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:51",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:51",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "stock_item": {
                    "item_id": 1,
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "stock_id": 1,
                    "qty": 100,
                    "is_in_stock": true,
                    "is_qty_decimal": false,
                    "show_default_notification_message": false,
                    "use_config_min_qty": true,
                    "min_qty": 0,
                    "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
                    "max_sale_qty": 10000,
                    "use_config_backorders": true,
                    "backorders": 0,
                    "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
                    "notify_stock_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_qty_increments": true,
                    "qty_increments": 0,
                    "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
                    "enable_qty_increments": false,
                    "use_config_manage_stock": true,
                    "manage_stock": true,
                    "low_stock_date": null,
                    "is_decimal_divided": false,
                    "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
                }
                "website_ids": [
                    1
                ],
                "category_links": [
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "3"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "product_links": [
                {
                    "sku": "24-MB01",
                    "link_type": "crosssell",
                    "linked_product_sku": "24-WG086",
                    "linked_product_type": "simple",
                    "position": 1
                }
            ],
            "options": [],
            "media_gallery_entries": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "media_type": "image",
                    "label": "Image",
                    "position": 1,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "types": [
                        "image",
                        "small_image",
                        "thumbnail"
                    ],
                    "file": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "tier_prices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "image",
                    "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "small_image",
                    "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "description",
                    "value": "<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.<p>\n<ul>\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\n</ul>"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "sku": "24-MB04",
            "name": "Strive Shoulder Pack",
            "attribute_set_id": 15,
            "price": 32,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "created_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:52",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:52",
            "extension_attributes": {

                "stock_item": {
                    "item_id": 2,
                    "product_id": 2,
                    "stock_id": 2,
                    "qty": 100,
                    "is_in_stock": true,
                    "is_qty_decimal": false,
                    "show_default_notification_message": false,
                    "use_config_min_qty": true,
                    "min_qty": 0,
                    "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
                    "max_sale_qty": 10000,
                    "use_config_backorders": true,
                    "backorders": 0,
                    "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
                    "notify_stock_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_qty_increments": true,
                    "qty_increments": 0,
                    "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
                    "enable_qty_increments": false,
                    "use_config_manage_stock": true,
                    "manage_stock": true,
                    "low_stock_date": null,
                    "is_decimal_divided": false,
                    "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
                }

                "website_ids": [
                    1
                ],
                "category_links": [
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "3"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "product_links": [
                {
                    "sku": "24-MB04",
                    "link_type": "crosssell",
                    "linked_product_sku": "24-UG03",
                    "linked_product_type": "simple",
                    "position": 1
                }
            ],
            "options": [],
            "media_gallery_entries": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "media_type": "image",
                    "label": "Image",
                    "position": 1,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "types": [
                        "image",
                        "small_image",
                        "thumbnail"
                    ],
                    "file": "/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "tier_prices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "image",
                    "value": "/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "small_image",
                    "value": "/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "description",
                    "value": "<p>Convenience is next to nothing when your day is crammed with action. So whether you're heading to class, gym, or the unbeaten path, make sure you've got your Strive Shoulder Pack stuffed with all your essentials, and extras as well.</p>\n<ul>\n<li>Zippered main compartment.</li>\n<li>Front zippered pocket.</li>\n<li>Side mesh pocket.</li>\n<li>Cell phone pocket on strap.</li>\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap and top carry handle.</li>\n</ul>"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "activity",
                    "value": "11,21,23,18"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "style_bags",
                    "value": "27,29,30"
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Magento2 does not suggest to add stock info to listing Api a MSI add to 2.3 version.**

***But if you want don't use MSI to your system then you can below solution***

## 1.Create `di.xml` at your `app/code/StackExchange/Magento`

Update `ExtensionPool` data of `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface` and add `stock_item` data provider.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="extensionActions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="read" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="stock_item" xsi:type="string">StackExchange\Magento\Model\ReadHandler</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

## 2. Define **ReadHandler** class.

```
 <?php

namespace StackExchange\Magento\Model;


class ReadHandler implements \Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
     */
    private $stockRegistry;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry     
    ) {

        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }
    /**
     * Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface
     * @param type $product
     * @param type $arguments
     */
    public function execute($product, $arguments = [])
    {
        if ($product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem() !== null) {
            return $product;
        }

        $stockItem =$this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId());
        $extensionAttributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes->setStockItem($stockItem);
        $product->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);

        return $product;        
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you any idea Pleas give solution.
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287627/magento-2-rest-api-products-custom-attributes-add-selected-attribute-value-l

Comment: @Amit - Thank you . Its working for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Magento 2.3.1, upon running the upgrade command I get XML errors.  `Element 'item': The type definition is abstract.`