# How to get Product Custom attribute Using REST API in magento2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3, magento2.3.4, magento2.3.5-p1

Hello I call the below API to get Product information

Url: `URL: http://localhost/magentosample230/rest/V1/products/24-MB04`

Type: `GET`

I got the Follow out put:

```
{
        "attribute_code": "material",
        "value": "5459,5460,5463,5465"
    }
```

But i want following output:

```
{
        "attribute_code": "material",
        "value": "Canvas,Cotton,Mesh,Polyester"
    }
```

Please help me i try all solution of other stackexchange answer but not working in magento2.3.4

If someone help me its helpful

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/291051/85907

Comment: Its useful....Thnx buddy

Comment: above comment i  convert into answer and you kindly accept answer @Magento??

Comment: Yes it is working code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In above comment follow this link and get value using attribute code. Check this link

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/291051/85907**

**`THANKS`**