# Magento 2 REST API - How to add product custom attribute type file upload to a product when adding a product

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api

I'm working on a project where my product has some datasheets that has to be uploaded to the website. Right now I've created one product attribute named datasheet with attribute type file upload. I'm able to create product using REST API. But the problem is I cannot able to add this files through API as I'm confused how to add this through it.

I know that we can use

`"custom_attributes": [     { "attribute_code": "item_ship_day", "value": "Ships in 2 days" }, }`

works for normal attributes. But what about **file upload**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom module to add your attachments to the product's custom_attributes

A detailed answer can be found [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/287627/magento-2-rest-api-products-custom-attributes-add-selected-attribute-value-l)

Comment: thank you for your response. But my requirement doesn't comes under this point. Is there any way in magento to upload custom attribute value file as base64encoded value or upload file from path

Comment: If you want to add a custom attribute and want to get it out via the API, you have no choice but to create a custom_attribute. Also if you want to upload through Magento then you won't get this data via API.